# Flash cs6 as3: Programmatically changing the movieclip associated with a class without using an instance of the class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm in the process of creating a game. I'd like my main character to be able to programmatically equip weapons/armor whatnot. He has a hand that if I manually edit a sword into, the animation works fine, however I don't want him to start with a sword equipped.

Unfortunately I can't access an instance of this hand because it's only present for 10 frames during the attack animation. If I set an instance name for the hand in the timeline (Frames 110-120) I can't refer to it from the character class.

Is there a way to access my "arm" class and programmatically add my sword sprite to the associated movieclip without having an accessible instance of the arm class? I've considered swapping out the arm movieclip for one with a sword already added - but I run into the same problem of not being able to access an instance which is only present during some of the frames.

I've tried to make my question as clear as possible, hopefully it worked. Thank you very much for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Just keep the hand and sword present all the time, and change their `.visible` property as needed.

Comment: Is this the best way to do it if I end up having 100+ different weapons? Not that I'm planning on it, but I'm curious as to whether that's the way it's traditionally done.

Comment: You need to show your code of how you're currently "uquipping" for anyone to really help you.

Comment: How one would "traditionally" do this is with class files and not timeline code - as timeline code is clumsy.   Best way would be to have code in your arm/hand class (or timeline) that runs when it's created to know whether it should have a sword (and which one) and create it (or not) as needed.

Comment: RE: Visibility with 100+ weapons  -  it would be fine if had a master sword MovieClip and kept your individual swords as different frames of that timeline, then you only have once instance loaded at any time.

Comment: To more directly answer your question.  What you have to do is create global variables (or at least variables higher up the scope than your hand class) that store what is equipped, then when you hand comes on the screen use said variables to initialize it properly.

Comment: I've been trying to do it the "traditional" way of having class files, the problem I'm running into is that I can't add the "Arm" class as a child (in order to control it through a parent) without an instance of the Arm class, is there something I'm missing there? A way to add a whole Class and not just an instance as a child? I'd be much more comfortable doing it that way haha.

Comment: Awesome I'll give that a try thank you! Is there a reason I can't accept your answer yet? I'm not seeing any options for that.

Comment: Because I haven't submitted an answer, only comments.  Mostly because you've asked too general of a question that has too many potential answers.  StackOveflow is meant for more speicfic questiosn.

Comment: Ohh! That makes sense. Well seeing as you've answered my overly general question I'd be glad to accept your comment if you submit it as an answer, if that helps you out. It might help some others down the line too. Otherwise thanks again and cheers!

Comment: Update: I gave it a try. When the hand came on the screen I added arm1, an instance of the Arm class, as a child. it worked while arm1 was on the screen, but as soon as the instance, arm1, left the screen I could no longer access it (arm1.parent was null) Any more advice =X?

Comment: That is as expected.  `parent` and `stage` are set to null when something is removed from the timeline.  You really need to show your code so you can get a proper answer.

Comment: I would but my code is literally all over the place in various frames and classes and it's not worth the trouble for me, and definitely not for you! Guess I'll just keep trying different things til I figure it out haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easiest (though not best) way you could do this.

On your main (root) timeline, put the following code:

```
var weaponId:int = 1;  //never modify this directly, use the function below so the event gets dispatached. - This value will correspond to frame in your weapon movieClip that will contain the correct graphic of the selected weapon.

function changeWeapon(id:int):void {
    weaponId = id;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("WeaponChange")); //this will dispatch an event, so anything listening for this event will know it's been changed
}
```

On your hand timeline, put the following code:

```
MovieClip(root).addEventListener("WeaponChange",updateWeapon,false,0,true); //listen for when the weapon changes

updateWeapon(); //update the weapon immediately to the current value

function updateWeapon(e:Event = null):void {
    weapon.gotoAndStop(MovieClip(root).weaponId); //assuming your hand timeline has a movieClip on it called weapon and each frame of weapon corresponds to the weaponId
}
```

---

Here is what's happening:

Whenever you change weapons (however that's done), call the function `changeWeapon()` on the root timeline.  This will set the variable and dispatch an event. If the hand is present, it will see the event and update itself.  If the hand is not present, when the hand get instantiated next it will look at the global variable and change accordingly.